# C++ class instance identifier undeclared

Tags: c++, dev-c++, undeclared-identifier

So, I'm trying to compile my code, but the compiler keeps complaining that "'mysnake' undeclared (first use this function)", but I declared it.
This is my Main.cpp, wehre it is declared.

```
#include "Class.h"
#include "Snake.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    Prog run;
    if((run.Init())==false){
      return(1);
      }
    Snake mysnake;
    if(run.LoadFiles()==false){
      return(1);
      }
    run.MainLoop();
    if(run.Draw()==false){
      return(1);
      }
    run.CleanUp();
    return(0);
}
```

And this is the file that makes the compiler complain (AFAIK it's the first file with any reference to 'mysnake' that gets compiled)

```
#include "Class.h"
#include<sstream>
#include "Snake.h"

bool Prog::Draw(){
     std::stringstream message;
     SDL_Rect position;
     SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screen, NULL);
     int s=mysnake.EndSnake();
     message<<"Your snake was "<<s<<" blocks long.";
     msg=TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, message.str().c_str(), font_color);
     if(msg==NULL){
       return(false);
       }
     position.x=(WWIDTH-msg->w)/2;
     position.y=(WHEIGHT-msg->h)/2;
     SDL_BlitSurface(msg, NULL, screen, &position);
     SDL_Flip(screen);
     return(true);
     }
```

I have thought about it for over an hour and I still can't understand why it does this. By the way I'm using Bloodshed Dev C++
I'd be very grateful for help.

Comment: What you declare in one function doesn't spread across every function. That would cause extreme name conflict issues.

Comment: What chris just said, the mysnake object is not known in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `Draw` function there is no variable declared called `mysnake`. That function can't see the `mysnake` that's declared in `main` because it is *local* to `main`. You need to pass your `mysnake` object to the `Draw` function so that it knows which snake you're actually talking about.

To do that, give `Draw` an argument of type `const Snake&`, a "reference to `const Snake`" (or take away the `const` if `EndSnake` is a non-`const` member function):

```
bool Prog::Draw(const Snake& snake) {
  // ...
}
```

And when you call `Draw` in `main`, do this:

```
run.draw(mysnake);
```

Now your `Draw` function has a variable called `snake` which was passed in from `main`. Because the argument is a reference, the `Snake` object that it sees is exactly the same object as in `main`. If the argument had been of type `Snake` instead of `const Snake&`, then you would get a copy of the `mysnake` from `main`.

---

Some extra advice:

We usually write conditions like `(run.Init())==false` as just `!run.init()` - it reads much  better. Returning is also usually written as `return true;`, rather than `return(true);`, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I got the idea that instances of classes are global by default...obviously I was wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `mysnake` is declared in `main` does not allow one to use it in `Prog`. You probably want to transmit a reference to mysnake to the Draw method.
Through the constructor or through the call to the method.

```
Prog run(mysnake);
run.draw();
```

or

```
run.draw(mysnake);
```